# Preferred way to pass data while uploading Blob

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am currently working on an AppEngine application that can receive file uploads. I prepare the upload data and pass the id of my DataStorage object along with the POST request.

The live version of the AppEngine quits with an internal server error, if I pass them as query string appended to the upload URL. This works with the development version. I then tried to read the raw data myself, which again works locally, but not on the live server.

Does anyone know the recommended way to access and pass data? The documentation says that the form fields remain avaiable, but does not describe how to access them.

many thank in advance for any ideas.

Edit: I have found something that looks like a recommendation, but does not work either:
http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/kb/java.html#fileforms

Comment: what are you running on python, Go or Java?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to say: I am using Java

Comment: Are you trying to both POST and add query parameters? Or are you including extra parameters in the form?

Comment: I have tried both, independently from another

Answer (score 0):

Pass the additional parameters as extra form fields. They can be accessed in the same manner you would usually access form fields in a servlet.

Comment: I can do so in the local dev environment, but the InputStream on AppEngine is empty. I now have changed the underlying code and add the query string when creating the forward-url for the upload.